# Reading Data from a deserialized Json Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm currently designing a bot that receives data in the form of Json, after deserializing it into an array I try to search the information, this is where the problem comes in.

ProjectInfo class used for deserializing

```
namespace InfoClass
{
    public class ProjectInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string projectName { get; set; }
        public string clientName { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int sprintPhase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My main Json reader class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace InfoClass
{
    public class TestInfo
    {

        string json;
        public TestInfo()
        {

            if (json == null)
                InitializeJson();
        }

        private void InitializeJson()
        {
            json = @"{'CompanyData':[{id : 1 , companyName : 'Company1', projectName : 'TestProject1', clientName : 'TestClient1', sprintPhase : 2, status : 'Ongoing'},
                    {id : 2 , companyName : 'Company2', projectName : 'TestProject2', clientName : 'TestClient2', sprintPhase : 1 , status : 'Waiting on Designs'},
                    {id : 3 , companyName : 'Company3', projectName : 'TestProject3', clientName : 'TestClient3', sprintPhase : 5, status : 'Live'}]}";
        }


        public string GetStatus()
        {
            string status = "";
            ProjectInfo[] jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectInfo[]>(json);
            foreach (var companies in jsonArray)
            {
                foreach (var company in companies.projectName)
                {
                    if (company.Equals("TestProject3"))
                    {
                        status = "found";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = "not found";
                    }
                }

            }
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

My end goal of the application is for the user to type in a project name/company name and after that being able to see stuff like sprintPhase,status, and any other project related information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Linq` (add `using System.Linq;`) to filter `jsonArray`

```
var userFilter = jsonArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x.company == "UserInputCompanyName" || x.projectName == "UserCompanyName");
if(userFilter != null)
{
  // show stuff to user of userFilter
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, This did work, however my end goal is for a more dynamic search, so after TestCompany3 is found, i'd like to search projectName, clientsName, ect that is related to TestCompany3. Can this be done using the Linq, or is there a different way to do this ?

Comment: you can do this - just create a new linq expression and apply your filters

Comment: im not really sure what your result have to look like.

Comment: Something like, Testcompany3 found(Which your code does) then I'd like to pull the status of TestCompany3. So the output I'm looking for is TestCompany3, Status = Live.

Comment: you can do this e.g. myLabel.Text = userFilter.Status;